# React Native build error: Text must not be null or empty

Tags: react-native, jenkins, apk, node-modules

My Jenkins build has given me the following error:

```
13:18:22 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:18:22 
13:18:22 * Where:
13:18:22 Script '/Users/abcd/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ABCD/ABCDL/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 190
13:18:22 
13:18:22 * What went wrong:
13:18:22 A problem occurred evaluating settings 'AppName'.
13:18:22 > Text must not be null or empty
13:18:22
```

It seems the problem is with the `@react-native-community/cli-platform` node module, but reading over this closed issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25479

its unclear to me what exactly is the proposed and final solution to this.

There is a recommendation on a fix that is more straightforward in this react-native issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25822

but my error is not complaining about that line.

As far as installing `@react-native-community/cli` I believe I already have it inside my `package-lock.json` file:

```
"react-native": {
      "version": "0.60.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native/-/react-native-0.60.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-WE41lbGQjnzM9srIFtMDtMJkQAvk95iZwuFvAxl68s80bkYa7Ou9sGFHpeYIV6cY8yHtheCSo5q6YMxhdfkdOw==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/cli": "^2.0.1",
        "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^2.0.1",
        "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^2.0.1",
```

Others mentioned something about `app/build.gradle`, here is the relevant part of mine:

```
// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Mention was also made of `android/settings.gradle`, this one is mine:

```
rootProject.name = 'NFIBEngage'
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':appcenter-crashes'
project(':appcenter-crashes').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android')
include ':appcenter-analytics'
project(':appcenter-analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-analytics/android')
include ':appcenter'
project(':appcenter').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter/android')
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

From what I have gathered here:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.53.3&to=0.60.4

The above files are correct.

So what exactly is wrong here and how do I fix it?

In terms of `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle line 190` is this one:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(reactNativeConfigOutput)
```

Could the problem be with how I wrote index.js file:

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
// old config code
import KeyboardManager from "react-native-keyboard-manager";
// old config code ^^^
import NFIBEngage from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

// old config code
import { Sentry } from "react-native-sentry";

Sentry.config(
  "https://asdf@sentry.io/123456677"
).install();

KeyboardManager.setToolbarPreviousNextButtonEnable(true);
// old config code ^^^

AppRegistry.registerComponent("NFIBEngage", () => NFIBEngage);
```

Is `AppRegistry.registerComponent()` written correctly?

I ran the Jenkins script locally, which I believe is this script right here:

```
import fs from "fs-extra";
import eachSeries from "async/eachSeries";
import { exec } from "child_process";
import { androidDirectory } from "../../app.json";
import { resolveFromRoot, distDir, createLogger } from "../build";

const logger = createLogger("android");

const APK_PATTERN = /release\.apk$/i;

function copyArtifactsToDist() {
  logger.logHeader("Copying APK to Dist", { repeatChar: "=" });
  const baseDir = `${androidDirectory}/app/build/outputs/apk`;

  const allFlavs = ["dev", "qa", "ua", "prod"];
  const branchName = process.env.GitVersion_BranchName || "";
  const buildFlavour = branchName.startsWith("release/") ? allFlavs : ["dev"];
  const envs = {
    dev: "INT",
    qa: "QA",
    ua: "UA",
    prod: ""
  };

  buildFlavour
    .map(env => {
      const apkOutputDir = resolveFromRoot(`${baseDir}/${env}/release`);
      return {
        apkOutputDir,
        env
      };
    })
    .forEach(({ apkOutputDir, env }) => {
      const src = `${apkOutputDir}/app-${env}-release.apk`;
      //prettier-ignore
      const binaryName = env === 'prod' ? 'ENGAL.apk' : `ENGAL-${envs[env]}.apk`;
      const dest = `${distDir}/${binaryName}`;
      fs.copy(src, dest, (err: Error) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
        }
      });
    });
}

function run() {
  logger.logHeader("Starting Android Builds", { repeatChar: "#" });
  const flavours = [
    {
      endpoint: "dv",
      flavour: "Dev",
      appcenterKey: "<hashKeys>"
    },
    {
      endpoint: "qa",
      flavour: "Qa",
      appcenterKey: "<hashKeys>"
    },
    {
      endpoint: "ua",
      flavour: "Ua",
      appcenterKey: "<hashKeys>"
    },
    {
      endpoint: "prod",
      flavour: "Prod",
      appcenterKey: "<hashKeys>"
    }
  ];

  const versionCode = process.env.Build || 1;
  const release = process.env.GitVersion_MajorMinorPatch || "1.0.0";
  const fullAppVersion = `${release}-${versionCode}`;

  const devFlav = flavours.find(f => f.flavour.toLocaleLowerCase() === "dev");

  const branchName = process.env.GitVersion_BranchName || "";
  const buildFlavour = branchName.startsWith("release/") ? flavours : [devFlav];

  eachSeries(
    buildFlavour,
    (f, callback) => {
      //prettier-ignore
      logger.logHeader(
        `starting gradle assemble${f.flavour}Release with flag - versionName=${fullAppVersion} -PversionCode=${versionCode}`,
        {repeatChar: '-'}
      );

      const engaInfo = `ENGAGE_VERSION=${fullAppVersion}`;
      const engaEndpoint = `ENGAGE_ENDPOINT=${f.endpoint}`;
      const engaCenter = `APPCENTER_KEY=${f.appcenterKey}`;
      const engaPlatform = "APPCENTER_PLATFORM=android";
      //prettier-ignore
      const prepare = `${engaEndpoint} ${engaCenter} ${engaInfo} ${engaPlatform} npm run setup`;
      const cd = `cd ${androidDirectory}`;
      //prettier-ignore
      const releaseCmd = `./gradlew assemble${f.flavour}Release -PversionName=${fullAppVersion} -PversionCode=${versionCode} && cd ..`;

      exec(`${prepare} && ${cd} && ${releaseCmd}`, err => {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }

        logger.logHeader(`${f.flavour} Android Build Successful!`, {
          repeatChar: "#"
        });
        logger.close();
        callback(null);
      });
    },
    error => {
      if (error) {
        logger.logHeader("Android Builds Failed!", {
          repeatChar: "#"
        });
        logger.error(error);
        logger.close();
      }
      copyArtifactsToDist();
    }
  );
}

run();
```

via `npm run build` and locally I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleDevRelease' not found in root project 'AppName'. Some candidates are: 'assembleRelease'.
```

Are these related errors? Anyone experienced with React Native builds?

As suggested, I looked into my `android/app/build.gradle` file for `productFlavors` and noticed that indeed they were missing between here:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 123456 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
```

So I added it like so:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
      dev {
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName("INT")
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher("dv")
        applicationIdSuffix ".dv"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "<hash_id>",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "123456789"]
      }
      qa {
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName("QA")
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher("qa")
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "<hash_id>",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "123456789"]
      }
      ua {
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName("UA")
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher("ua")
        applicationIdSuffix ".ua"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "<hash_id>",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "123456789"]
      }
      prod {
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName()
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher()
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "<hash_id>",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "601125149914"]
      }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
```

The `buildTypes` is looking a bit different than the original legacy `buildTypes` so I am not sure if that's okay, but at any rate I then ran `npm run build` again locally and got this error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/android/app/build.gradle' line: 168

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method getAppName() for arguments [INT] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=dev, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.
```

I was able to resolve the local error by adding the missing methods like so:

```
def appName = "Engage";

/**
 * Get the version name from command line param
 *
 * @return int If the param -PversionName is present then return int value or -1
 */
def getAppName = { env ->
  return (env ? appName + " ("+ env + ")" : appName);
}

/**
 * Get the version name from command line param
 *
 * @return int If the param -PversionName is present then return int value or -1
 */
def getLauncher = { env ->
    return (env ? "engage-" + env + ".nfib.org" : "engage.nfib.org");
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nfib.engage"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
      dev {
        dimension 'default'
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName("INT")
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher("dv")
        applicationIdSuffix ".dv"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "b78285eb-f1ec-46f3-9ad0-c7efe691a401",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "584236827312"]
      }
      qa {
        dimension 'default'
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName("QA")
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher("qa")
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "e4280f5e-62ec-41a4-bd86-f5b94e471a36",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "162802054510"]
      }
      ua {
        dimension 'default'
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName("UA")
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher("ua")
        applicationIdSuffix ".ua"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "2ffd8dc0-9c6b-4035-999d-fc694194725a",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "594905904045"]
      }
      prod {
        dimension 'default'
        resValue "string", "app_name", getAppName()
        resValue "string", "link_launcher", getLauncher()
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "82dcb42f-1d35-4b79-bc28-2d1d02dbda36",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "601125149914"]
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I continue to get the same error in Jenkins.

Comment: Check if your react-native-community/cli is in the latest version. It's updated 35mins ago. [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cli)

Comment: @firats, I don't even have that package in my project: `✗ npm ls @react-native-community/cli
NFIBEngage@0.0.1 /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage
└── (empty)`

Comment: Actually some of the comments in your link points to install @react-native-community/cli as a solution. Did you try it?

Comment: @firats, I believe I address your question in what I just added.

Comment: From your package.json, your `cli` version is at `^2.0.1` and `2.0.1` is indeed the version of the cli that had the issue you linked to from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25479

Have you verified that the line similar to `def command = "../node_modules/.bin/react-native config"` (from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25479#issuecomment-508404360) in your `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle` is correct? You should also ensure your installed version of the cli is >= 2.0.2.

Comment: @azundo, I will look into it. I hope you are right I need to resolve this soon, I will let you know.

Comment: @azundo, I installed the latest versions of `@react-native-community/cli`, `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android` and `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios`, but for `react-native` 60.4 it still using the 2.0.2 versions as a dependency of it.

Comment: @firats, I just added some more information.

Comment: @azundo, I just added some more information.

Comment: @Daniel you'll need to make sure your `buildTypes` and `productFlavors` definitions in `android/app/build.gradle` are set up to include all the different variants you are trying to build in your jenkins job. Looks like you have flavors for `dev`, `qa`, `ua` and `prod`. Check out the gradle docs https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types for more info.

Comment: @azundo, you are on the right track here. It looks like I was missing `productFlavors`, but now I am getting a different error. Please see above. Thanks for sticking it out with me.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `getAppName` function in your build.gradle. Something like `ext.getAppName = {suffix = '' -> 'MyAppName' + suffix}`. A quick scan of your build.gradle looks like you need another called `getLauncher` which returns an appropriate string for whatever you use `link_launcher` for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197647/discussion-between-daniel-and-azundo).

Comment: In our case, we have an atypical structure since we added React Native to an existing Android application years ago. After changing the main app/module name to `app` and moving the entire Android application into a `android` sub directory, things started to work without an issue. 

I'm sure you could configure things to make the non-standard structure work, which we were doing previously, but with the advent of autolinking, the extra hoop jumping didn't feel warranted. So we caved to the defaults and are moving forward now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the changes to get the build working, from comments:

From your package.json, your cli version is at `^2.0.1` and `2.0.1` is indeed the version of the cli that had the issue you linked to from github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25479 Have you verified that the line similar to `def command = "../node_modules/.bin/react-native config"` (from github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/…) in your `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle` is correct? You should also ensure your installed version of the cli is >= `2.0.2`.

Make sure your `buildTypes` and `productFlavors` definitions in `android/app/build.gradle` are set up to include all the different variants you are trying to build in your jenkins job. Looks like you have flavors for `dev`, `qa`, `ua` and `prod`. Check out the gradle docs developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types for more info.

Looks like you're missing a `getAppName` function in your `build.gradle`. Something like `ext.getAppName = {suffix = '' -> 'MyAppName' + suffix}`. A quick scan of your `build.gradle` looks like you need another called `getLauncher` which returns an appropriate string for whatever you use `link_launcher` for.

Comment: the latter part has been resolved, I added the `def getAppName = { env ->` and `def getLauncher = { env ->`, but the problem persists in Jenkins. I will update the OP.

Comment: regarding the version of the `cli`, when I attempt that, it continues to install the same version even if I physically change it to `2.0.2`.

Comment: Where are you changing it? In the `@react-native-community/cli` entry in the `package-lock.json`? I typically use `yarn` and don't have experience with npm's built-in lock file but make sure you're changing the entry for the cli package and not the entry under `react-native`.

Comment: I removed it from the `package-lock.json` file and ran `npm install`, then I went back and changed it to the desired version manually and ran `npm install`, both times it installed the version I already had.

Comment: today I noticed I do not have `@react-native-community/cli` at all in my `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my node version on my CI tool and fixed this exact error.
I was previously on version 6 and bumped it to 10

Comment: I was on node version 11, I recently had to downgrade it to 10 to use `expo-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

**I have also face this problem**

very easy solution for this problem

**Remove node_module**

and

**Reinstall node_module :** npm install

react-native run-android