# Build error when react-native run-android on app with no change

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native 0.61 app which was running fine but is not without any change i am aware. Here is the error when `react-native run-android`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\D\code\js\emps_fe7\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Text must not be null or empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\D\code\js\emps_fe7\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Text must not be null or empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\d\code\js\emps_fe7\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\d\code\js\emps_fe7\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (C:\d\code\js\emps_fe7\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

What I did is to rebuild the project from the beginning and add each of the module one by one. However the error is exactly the same. The project used to be fine and apk has been generated out of it. I am kind lost here about what could go wrong. Here is the dependence of `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.11.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native build error: Text must not be null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297734/react-native-build-error-text-must-not-be-null-or-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Hello please add latest @react-native-community/cli-platform-android: "^3.0.3" and delete previous node module then run npm install in my case this issue fixed.
Please check below images.because new react native require locally installed react native cli instead of global react native cli.

[image: Please check image]